# How can I find Schengen visa rejection stats based on nationality and location?

Tags: schengen

For example I want to learn what percentage of Indian nationals are rejected in Schengen member embassies/consulates located in UAE.

Comment: I would be surprised if those stats were available. You can easily find the rejection rate for each consulate (so per Schengen state and per country of application), but apparently not with the additional dimension of nationality of the applicant.

Comment: Yes, I found them, but what I need is the kind of data I mentioned. It should be available somewhere

Comment: Not sure why “it should”. It is not required by Annex XII of the Schengen Visa Code which only requires totals. In most cases they probably consider that a majority of the applications in one country are from citizens of that country. You may try to ask the EC of check individual countries’ consulates but  it’s not part of standard reporting.

Comment: I’m not sure how the availability of the information you inquire about would have much of an influence on that. There are reports and statistics, and it is apparently felt that those are enough. If you don’t feel so, feel free to ask the EC about it.

Comment: Also don’t forget that if you go into to much detail, you’ll end up with categories with single digits, which may be a privacy concern. And finally, don’t forget that any accountability is to European citizens, not foreigners. Visas are a privilege, not a right.